# why new File() returns empty object in jsdom and valid file in chrome console

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I'm trying to create file with js:

```
const file = new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'chucknorris.png', { type: 'image/png' });
```

and in chrome console it is file
[image]

but in typescript playground it's empty object
[image]

same thing happens while writing tests
[image]

can someone explain the reason why this is happening?

tried passing `new Blob()`, `ArrayBuffer` as file bits, nothing changed.

Comment: Your File is fine, but you need to access all its properties yourself to log it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwDYFMYF4ZhQdxgMWRQAoBtAcmMARiQQtIB9GgSnIF0AaGc4ACwFdgA1mBAAnEQggA6AA5gA5uQ4BvGFACe0lAC5OCALYBDOSgD0shTAC+jANwAoUJBCpJSEHOKJUHLykkQEAC8UHyJJdU1QlyQDaABZEAATBEQURNsgA

Comment: @Kaiido by any chance do you know why trying to use `file.slice.arrayBuffer()` throws:
TypeError: file.slice(...).arrayBuffer is not a function

Comment: `file.slice.arrayBuffer()`? You missed the `()` to call `slice()`, so you're trying to get the method on the function`.slice`. `file.slice().arrayBuffer()` seems to work in TS playground.